# How to read the text file lines with passing over some lines?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have a text file that contains some info in lines. I wanna read it by passing over some lines. For example, let's say i have 1-10 in the lines. When i'm reading i want to read it in the following way,

```
1 <- i wanna read this
2 <- Skip this
3 <- read this 
4 <- Skip this
5 <- read this
6 <- Skip this
7 <- read this
8 <- Skip this
9 <- read this
10 <- Skip this
```

you get the pattern right? how can i achieve this using c#? and i wanna get the lines i skipped at a later time too. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you familiar with modular math?  If you % 2 your line number you can find out which are odd and which are even.  (Just a hint...)

Comment: Havent tried any actually. I can't think of any

Answer (score 5):

You can use the overload of the LINQ `Where` that includes the index, and use `%` to filter every other line:

```
var everyOtherLine = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("path")
                                   .Where((s, i) => i % 2 == 0);
```

Comment: I dont get this solution. Is there any simpler way?

Comment: What part isn't clear?  `Where` returns only values that pass the given condition.  The condition in this case are the lines where the line number is even (`i % 2 == 0`).  This gets you the first, third, etc. lines

Comment: I will try that and let you know

Comment: I'd be shocked if it gets simpler than this.

Answer (score 1):

*Edited to use a lookup for even and odd lines.*

Just loop through and add to the result set according to your criteria?

```
var lines = new Dictionary<int, List<string>>() {
    { 0, new List<string>() },
    { 1, new List<string>() }
};

using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filename)) {
    int i=0;
    while (!sr.EndOfStream) {
        string line = sr.ReadLine();
        lines[i%2].Add(line);
    }
}
```

Then *lines[0]* gets you the even lines, and *lines[1]* gets you the odd ones.

Comment: If OP wants to read the lines skipped later, perhaps she can read both at the same time into memory.

Comment: @BenSchwehn good call, updated.  Honestly though I like Bort's answer, it's much more readable.

Answer (score 1):

Pseudocode:

```
for (i=0; i<filelines.Count; i++)
{
 if (i mod 2 == 1) oddlines.Add(filelines[i]);
}
```

Edit: dbaseman did it precisely, thanks.